# How do I create a multidimensional http-post array in JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp, http-post, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to submit (post) a multidimensional (2D) html-form to a JSP.

In HTML there's the following code:

```
<tr class="odd">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="row1['attribute']" value="Druckerei" id="attribute-1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <label for="attribute-1">Druckerei</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="row1['weight']" size="3" value="0" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="row2['attribute']" value="Erscheinungstag" checked="checked" id="attribute-2" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <label for="attribute-2">Erscheinungstag</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="row2['weight']" size="3" value="0" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Is there in **JSP** a way to handle the 2D post data (perhaps similar to PHP)?

Would it be easier if I had different HTML-Code?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**No you cannot have 2D array like Rows and Columns**. But you `can achieve this by sending multiple values for a POST data parameter` which works like this:

**Your Form might look like this:**

```
<tr class="odd">
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="attribute" value="Druckerei" id="attribute-1" />
</td>
<td>
    <label for="attribute-1">Druckerei</label>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="weight" size="3" value="0" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="attribute" value="Erscheinungstag" 
     checked="checked" id="attribute-2" />
</td>
<td>
    <label for="attribute-2">Erscheinungstag</label>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="weight" size="3" value="0" />
</td>
</tr>
```

**And your POST Data will be sent like:**

```
url?attribute=Druckerei,Erscheinungstag&weight=3,3
```

**From the servlets you can access the the POST parameter like:**

```
String[] attributes = request.getParameterValues("attribute");
String[] weights = request.getParameterValues("weight");
```

Comment: Can I be sure all the Param-Values will be in the same order?